# Checking radio button on submit - PHP

Tags: php

I need to check a radio button input on submit.

If none of the radio buttons are checked, `$err1_diet` gets set to true and the `red` class needs to be added.

And I also need to know which radio button was checked since this isn't the only question in the form.

```
  if( !isset($_POST['diet']) ){
    $err1_diet = true;
  }elseif($_POST['diet'] == 1){
    $diet = true;
  }else{
    $diet = false;
    $yes = true;
  }

<p class="<?php echo (($err1_diet == true) ? "red" : "" ); ?>">&#8226; Are you on a diet?<?php var_dump($err1_diet); ?></p>
<input type="radio" name="diet" value="1" <?php echo (($diet) ? 'checked="true"' : "" ); ?> /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" <?php echo (($diet) ? '' : 'checked="true"' ); ?> /> No
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this code? it seems fine to me.

Comment: it s not checking the right button after input. I m just missing something. long day.

Comment: Actually no ... it's checking one of the radio buttons before the form is submitted. That's the problem.

Comment: i'd suggest just use a checkbox, using radio buttons for yes or no for radio buttons without a default checked state denotes a yes a no and undefined. with a checkbox, just use a ternary isset and its done

Comment: so just have one check box for yes?

Comment: that s so much better.

Comment: @ciprian yes, just a simple `$diet = isset($_POST['diet']);` you'll get `true/false (boolean)`. then you get to echo the attribute at just one checkbox

Comment: add an answer if you want

Comment: here's the thing ... i need to have two radio buttons one with yes, one with no. the question is mandatory. i have to know if it's yes or no. if yes is checked i know that diet is true, but leaving the checkbox un checked can also mean that the user forgot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually no ... it's checking one of the radio buttons before the form is submitted. That's the problem

You can solve your problem using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'` for example:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' and !isset($_POST['diet']) ){
    $err1_diet = true;
  }elseif($_POST['diet'] == 1){
    $diet = true;
  }else{
    $diet = false;
    $yes = true;
  }

<p class="<?php echo (($err1_diet == true) ? "red" : "" ); ?>">&#8226; Are you on a diet?<?php var_dump($err1_diet); ?></p>
<input type="radio" name="diet" value="1" <?php echo (($diet) ? 'checked="true"' : "" ); ?> /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" <?php echo (($diet) ? '' : 'checked="true"' ); ?> /> No
```